# Why are different colors, according to sugar concentration observed in Benedict's test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, biochemistry, coordination-compounds

Colors range from green yellow orange to red. How does the sugar concentration and Cu2O concentration cause this?
I know Cu2O is red. **Why is there a green or yellow color** instead of just red or some kind of red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benedict's Reagent is just simply $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions in the form of copper citrate. When Benedict's Reagent finds an aldose (a sugar with an aldehyde group), it can oxidize the aldose to a carboxylic acid. For example:

[image: D-Glucose being oxidized]

Since D-Glucose is oxidized, Cu is reduced to a red precipitate ($\ce{Cu2O}$). The colors range form green to red because the original Copper Citrate ([$\ce{C6H8Cu2O7^4+}$](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/120942#section=Top)) is blue in color.

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-Benedicts-reagent-work-when-it-is-mixed-and-boiled-with-monosaccharide-disaccharide-and-polysaccharide-respectively)

Comment: how does it become green if cu2o is red?

Comment: "The compound can appear either yellow or red, depending on the size of the particles." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(I)_oxide yellow + blue =...

Comment: How does that relate to concentration? And what about green?

Comment: Color theory - Yellow Copper(I) Oxide + Blue Copper Citrate = Green solution

Comment: So at higher concentrations copper oxide particles clump together?